# Sending data from the form to an email with jQuery ajax and redirect to another page with passing POST variables not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have my own form in Wordpress, which after filling in and clicking submit redirects to the page with thanks and data from this form. At the same time, but before redirecting the same data from the form are sent to the user and admin emails. The steps of the whole process are as follows.

1. Form validation in jQuery Validate
2. Sending data from the form to an
   e-mail using jQuery ajax
3. Redirecting to the page thanking you and
   sending the variables from the form to this page using the POST
   method (jQuery + PHP).

jQuery code:

```
// validation
  $('#registration_form').validate({
    rules: {
      training_name: "required",
      training_place: "required",
      training_date: "required",
      participants_number: {
        required: true,
        range: [0,100]
      },
    (...) // etc 
  });



// jQuery ajax email sending
 $('#registration_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).valid()) {
      let formData = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url: ajax.url,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
        },
        data: { 
          action: 'registerFormSendEmail', 
          form_data: formData
        },
        success: function(res) {
          // console.log(res);
        }
      });
      // return false;
    }
  });
```

In html form code I have action name with permalink to Thank you Page with POST variables.
The problem is that sometimes sending emails and redirecting with POST variables works, and sometimes not. Most often it doesn't work on Safari. Someone has an idea why and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The developer console gave you some error/warning?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. It turned out later that e-mails were not sent in browsers other than Safari too. **The problem was that sometimes the website redirected faster than the email was sent using Ajax** (it probably depends on the speed of the Internet connection).
I used the **.when()** and **.then()** functions. I modified the ajax function in such a way that form data firstly had to be successfully sent to the e-mail and then submitted the form and redirected to the 'thank you' page.

```
$('#submit_registration').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#registration_form').valid()) {
      let formData = $('#registration_form').serialize();
      var checkEmailSent;
      $.when(
        $.ajax({
          url: ajax.url,
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'JSON',
          cache: false,
          data: { 
            action: 'registerFormSendEmail', 
            form_data: formData,
          },
          success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            if (res !== 'sent') {
              alert('Error in sending e-mail.');
              checkEmailSent = false;
            }
          }
        })
      ).then(function() {
        if (checkEmailSent == false) {
          return false;
        } else {
          $('#registration_form').submit();
        }
      });
    }
  });
```